# How to run a JSP website in localhost ? What is the environment to set up?

Tags: java

I am a PHP programmer.But i have a website code which was developed in jsp technology..

I dont know the environment of jsp engine. I wan to run my website in my localhost using Tomcat server..Please help me to do that...

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install and download [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). Of course you need to have a Java runtime in your machine. The website should have been given to you as a WAR file. To install it, simply copy the WAR file in the webapps folder of Tomcat. If you only have a bunch of JSP files, put them in the ROOT folder of Tomcat.

Comment: Alternatively if you are working on a maven-project you could simply use the tomcat plugin @ http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html